# Update column value and return updated value in same query MySQL, Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I know similar questions exist in which the user is trying to retrieve key generated of new row and the same thing as i want in PHP but i want to know its alternate for java. This is what i want:

```
String query = "UPDATE table SET tabValue = (tabValue+number) WHERE id="+xyz;
```

**I want to retrieve the tabValue after it is being updated in the same query**! Is it possible or do i have to write another query for it? 
Can anyone help me out here please?
NOTE: I am using JDBC.

Comment: *WHERE id="+xyz* SQL injection here.

Comment: Its just an example. I could do it in a safe way actually.

Comment: Why is this Java specific? You probably should mention the SQL server you are using.

Comment: That would be phpMyadmin

Comment: Why can't you just use `tabValue+number` in your Java code?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is the administration tool. you are using MySQL. I think you have to use a StoredProcedure for your solution.

Comment: So i wrote it in the heading :( I wrote java because i read that the id of a new row generated is returned via java code so that is why i mentioned java and mysql in the headline.

Comment: If using `Statement#executeUpdate()` will return the number of affected rows, if affected row count is not zero, use `tabValue+number`

Comment: @NitinDandriyal how am i supposed to used `tabValue`? I will have to retrieve it first. Wont i?

Comment: In java you can get AUTO_INCREMENT field (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id.html), but not an any field from insert/update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

You cannot refer to the `table` which is being updated in a `FROM` clause.

You are better off just keeping track of what the new value will be after `UPDATE` in your Java code.